# I need to only get all active users in a Security Group, i can list all users but i get both active and inactive users

Tags: active-directory, powershell, scripting, users

Need help to correct the scipt. The group FA-xxx-yyy-zzz has loads of users and undergroups in it.

This what i figured out so far is:

**Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "FA-xxx-yyy-zzz" -Recursive | Get-ADUser -Property Name | Select-Object Name**

this lists 1701 users and groups both active and inactive members and look like this

### **Name**

**John Doh (xxx32)**

---

But this gives only the specific FA group and missing the undergroups but in the format i would like to see it in with the column True or Not true parameter:

**$group = "FA-xxx-yyy-zzz"
$adusers = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group | where {$*.objectclass -eq "user"}
foreach ($activeuser in $adusers)
{
Get-ADUser -Identity $activeuser | where {$*.enabled -eq $true} | select Name, SamAccountName, UserPrincipalName, Enabled
}**

**Name                    SamAccountName     UserPrincipalName          Enabled

---

John Doh (xxx32)        xxx32              john.doh@contoso.com       True**